# How do I edit company pages?

Tags: support, developer-story

In my [Stack Overflow Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/102205) there are links to the companies I’ve added work history for. For example, one of my current positions is Director at Your Fight Site.

“Your Fight Site” in my Story is hyperlinked to a company page, but there’s nothing on there other than an out-of-date logo.

How can I update the logo on this company page, and add any other information?

Answer (score 3):

We don't currently offer the facility for users to edit the data associated with these pages. I've verified that you are the director of the company so if you can provide an up to date logo (maybe by editing your post) then I'll happily update it for you.

That said, I'll bring up with the team why we don't allow this if you were the person that created the company.

Comment: I’m still unable to update company pages. The company [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/400665/your-fight-site?storyType=1) is my company; I’m its only employee. The logo and website URL are both grossly out of date now.

Comment: Same issue here. No updates?