# How do I edit the 'Organisation' shown in my Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story, companies-page

My developer story includes a link to my current business - which I am the sole operator/employee of. I've just checked and it is displaying a person I have never heard of in the role of 'Translator'.

How might that have happened, and what can I do to fix it? I would like to make other updates to the organisation page (change the logo, etc) - but my main priority is removing this other user's listing.

I have since removed the link from my story and re-created it. The [organisation now shows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/386755/companion-studio?storyType=1) the other user only, but still has my logo and URL attached.

Comment: Hi.  I'm going to migrate this to Meta Stack Overflow since the developer story is specific to that site and there are more people there than here who'll be able to help you.

Comment: Can you include the link of the page you are seeing this on? I can only find https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/417626/companion-studio?storyType=1, which only lists you.

Comment: Updated question, thanks @MartijnPieters

Comment: A similar question that was sorta kinda answered: [How do I edit company pages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357509/451518). As far as I understand, you should go through [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't offer any way to edit the information shown on those pages. If you'd like to change any of it, you'll need to simply delete it from your story and create a new list using updated information, as you've already done.

As such, we also do not offer any way of moderating who lists those companies in their developer stories. There's no way to forcibly remove the reference made by a user.

Comment: Hmm - I might need to add a request for that feature, then. If I understand it, there's nothing to stop me listing myself as CEO of Ferrari, and nothing that Ferrari can do to change it if I do?

Comment: No, there's not. It's a pretty much entirely unmaintained feature at the moment. If it ever started causing way too many headaches, I'd venture a guess we're more likely to just completely remove the "lists" thing and go back to just having plain text in the developer story for company names.